# Calling member function in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a type called budget defined as

```
create type budget as object ( 
    year number,
    amount number,
    member function left_over (year in number) return number
)
```

Body:

```
create type body budget as
    member function left_over(year in number) return number is
    begin
        return amount;
    end left_over;
end;
```

And an object table

```
create table budget_table of budget;
```

How do I use the member function to return the amount? Something like:

```
select b.left_over(2010) from budget_table b;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a parameter to the method:

```
SQL> create or replace type budget as object (
  2      year number,
  3      amount number,
  4      member function left_over return number
  5  )
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type body budget as
  2      member function left_over return number is
  3      begin
  4          return amount;
  5      end left_over;
  6  end;
  7  /

Type body created.

SQL> create table budget_table of budget;

Table created.

SQL> insert into budget_table values (budget(2010,99));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select b.left_over() from budget_table b;

B.LEFT_OVER()
-------------
           99
```

(I assume this is an academic exercise, as it would make no sense to create tables like this in a real business database!)

To restrict to the budget for a particular year:

```
SQL> insert into budget_table values (budget(2010,99));

1 row created.
SQL> select b.left_over() from budget_table b;

B.LEFT_OVER()
-------------
           88
           99

SQL> select b.left_over() from budget_table b
  2  where b.year = 2010;

B.LEFT_OVER()
-------------
           99
```

Comment: It is academic. Also is it possible to pass in a value so i can just get the 2010 budget and not 2009 etc. thanks.

Comment: See updated answer - you wouldn't use a parameter to do that, you would select the row you want the amount for.

Comment: thanks but part of the requirements is that it gets passed into the function. That why i had the parameter in my original attempt...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - you might just as well create a stand-alone function if that is the goal!  You are going to have to select the data from the relevant row.

Comment: Maybe you should post the assignment question - it could be you have misunderstood it?

Comment: Using the budget information, a Manager should also be able to calculate at any time, the amount she/he has left to spend in the year. In order to achieve this she/he requires a function which takes in the year and returns the amount left to spend.

Comment: That says a function, not necessarily a method function of an object.

Answer (score 1):

It is a scoping issue.  Your function `left_over()` is a method on `Budget`, which is an individual thing.  However, you want to have a method which does a look up from a range of budgets.  The method as you have written it cannot do this, because an instance can only know about itself.  How can the `Budget` for 2009 possibly know the figures for 2010?

What you need is an object `Budgets` which has a collection of `Budget` as an attribute, and a member function  `left_over()` which returns the whatever for a given `Budget` in its collection.  Of course, the only way of getting that information is for the method to iterate over the collection, which will perform far less efficiently than a WHERE clause on a regular table but seems to be the standard approach in OO data practices.

Comment: Could you provide a quick code snippet of what you mean? Do you mean create a `budgets` table which has an object type column of `Budget`?